# sending form data with jquery ajax by replacing field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have form with field names with prefix post_.

eg post_url.

i need to replace post_url to url and then same for all fields and have to send thru ajax form data.

```
    var postData=$("#post_requestform").serialize();
console.log(postData);
var res = postData.split("&");
var str = "";
var str1=[];
for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
  {
    var key=res[i].split("=")[0];
    var val=res[i].split("=")[1];console.log(val);
    key=key.replace("post_","");
    str += key + "=" + val+ "&";
     str1[key]=val;
  }




       $.ajax({

url : "{{route('request.save')}}" ,

method: "POST",
  // traditional: true,

data :str, // post data || get data
// async: false,
// processData: false,
// contentType: false,

//data : { _token: '{{csrf_token()}}' },

error: function(data){

  console.log(data);

  toastr.error("Error Occured. Please Try Again Later.");

},

success : function(result){

  result = JSON.stringify(result)

 console.log(result);
}
});
```

But the form data not passing in ajax.please help.

Thanks,
Sarnitha

Comment: What is the "Content-Type" you are trying to use? `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json`?

Answer (score 0):

First use $("form").serializeArray(); then you will get form values in the form of an array, then perform required replace filters and prepare URI-encoded string :)

```js
$(function(){
$("#user_form").submit(function(){
    var formValues = $("#user_form").serializeArray();
    var postData = "";
    for(let prop of formValues){
        if (postData != "") {
            postData += "&";
    }
    postData += prop.name.replace("post_","") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(prop.value);
    }
    console.log(postData);
});
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
    <form action="javascript:void(0)" id="user_form">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="post_fname" value="John"><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="post_lname" value="Doe"><br>
        <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="age" name="post_age" value="23"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 

</body>
</html>
```